# Removing a string from a list inside a list of lists

Tags: python

What I'm trying to achieve here in a small local test is to iterate over an array of strings, which are basically arrays of strings inside a parent array.

I'm trying to achieve the following...

- 1) Get the first array in the parent array
- 2) Get the rest of the list without the one taken
- 3) Iterate through the taken array, so I take each of the strings
- 4) Look for each string taken in all of the rest of the arrays
- 5) If found, remove it from the array

So far I've tried the following, but I'm struggling with an error that I don't know where it does come from...

```
lines = map(lambda l: str.replace(l, "\n", ""),
            list(open("PATH", 'r')))

splitLines = map(lambda l: l.split(','), lines)

for line in splitLines:
    for keyword in line:
        print(list(splitLines).remove(keyword))
```

But I'm getting the following error...

```
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

Which isn't true as 'x' isn't a string included in any of the given test arrays.

SAMPLE INPUT (Comma separated lines in a text file, so I get an array of strings per line):

```
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['e', 'f', 'g'], ['b', 'q', 'a']]
```

SAMPLE OUTPUT:

```
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['e', 'f', 'g'], ['q']]
```

Comment: Can you show a sample input/desired output?

Comment: @chrisz sure, give me a minute

Comment: If its a sublist I think you have to index it further to find the element you want to remove.

Comment: @chrisz updated!

Comment: I'm confused as to why `b` and `a` are removed from the last list.  Because they are found in the first sublist?

Comment: @chrisz exactly. My intention is to iterate in order, so the first one is compared against the others. Clean the rest, and continue further with the rest of entries one by one.

Comment: Does order matter in the sublists?

Comment: @chrisz not at all, the only thing is being sure of taking each single list so every element in every list is compared against the rest but itself. It's like removing duplicates.

Comment: `splitLines` is a map object - you are trying to iterate over it but in the loop you exhaust it with `list(splitLines)` . That doesn't look like what you wanted. - You can only iterate over  a map object once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep track of previously seen strings using a `set` for fast lookups, and using a simple list comprehension to add elements not found in the previously seen `set`.

```
prev = set()
final = []
for i in x:
  final.append([j for j in i if j not in prev])
  prev = prev.union(set(i))

print(final)
```

Output:

```
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['e', 'f', 'g'], ['q']]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
inputlist = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['e', 'f', 'g'], ['b', 'q', 'a']]
scanned=[]

res=[]
for i in inputlist:
    temp=[]
    for j in i:
        if j in scanned:
            pass
        else:
            scanned.append(j)
            temp.append(j)
    res.append(temp)
```

---

```
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['e', 'f', 'g'], ['q']]
```